# Assistance with counter and score variables in Java Jeopardy game?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a class to keep score throughout my Jeopardy program. The question I have is how do I keep the variable persistent in the responsePrompt method as well as increasing or decreasing the variable in the score. Below is the code I have so far

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Game
{
public static void main(String[] args)
throws java.io.IOException
{
    menu();
    String[] jeoCategory = new String[]{"Brands", "Bands", "Lands", "Fact?", "France"};
    printCategory(jeoCategory);
    String[][] jeoBoard = new String[25][3];
    loadFile(jeoBoard);
}
public static void printCategory(String[] jeoCategory)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + jeoCategory[i] + "\t");
        if(i > 3)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
public static void menu()
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to Jeopardy " + "\n" +
                       "Enter the correct answer and win 10 points" + "\n" +
                       "Enter the incorrect answer and lose 10 points" + "\n");
}
public static void loadFile(String[][] jeoBoard)
throws java.io.IOException
{
    String filName = " ";
    filName = "C:\\temp\\JeopardyValues.txt";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(filName));
    for(int row = 0; row < 25; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
        {
            jeoBoard[row][col] = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
    input.close();
    printBoard(jeoBoard);
}
public static void printBoard(String[][] jeoBoard)
{
    for(int r = 0; r < 25; r++)
    {
        System.out.print("\t" + jeoBoard[r][2] + "\t");
        if(r == 4 || r == 9 || r == 14 || r == 19 || r == 24)
        {
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
    responsePrompt(jeoBoard);
}
public static void responsePrompt(String[][] jeoBoard)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner resp = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {  
        System.out.print("Pick a question: ");
        int ans = input.nextInt();

        if(ans > 25 || ans < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection, please choose a number on the board");
            break;
        }          
        if(jeoBoard[ans - 1][2].equals(" "))
        {
            System.out.println("That question has already been answered, please pick another");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(jeoBoard[ans - 1][0]);
        System.out.print("Your answer: ");
        String questResponse = resp.nextLine();
        if(questResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(jeoBoard[ans - 1][1]))
        {
            score++;
            System.out.println("Correct " + "\t" + score);
            jeoBoard[ans - 1][2] = " ";
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            score--;
            System.out.println("Incorrect " + "\t" + score);
            jeoBoard[ans - 1][2] = " ";
            counter++;
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        printBoard(jeoBoard);
        if(counter == 25)
        {
            break;
        }                 
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

}

Comment: Make the variable which you wanna be persistent as `static`. Warning- I haven't gone through your code,just a random piece of advice based on question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want your `score` to be set to 0 every time `responsePrompt` is called you should make it a global variable (outside of the methods) and your break is exiting the `for` loop. I am not sure that you want to do that, I belive that you are trying to get the user to enter a different number that is valid. You should do a

```
  while (ans > 25 || ans < 0 || jeoBoard[ans - 1][2].equals(" "))
{
    System.out.println("Invalid selection, please choose a number on the board");
    ans = input.nextInt();
}
```

I hope that helps.